# After using forkjoinpool with parallel stream, code after futureTask met multi-thread problem

Tags: java, java-stream, forkjoinpool

I want to use parallel stream api to read redis, get all items, and randomly sample 10% out of all items.
But I found it sometimes throws exception says `random.nextInt(itemCount)` does not accept 0 as input. It confuses me a lot.

Is it a multi-thread problem? I don't know what to do.

Here is the code:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer(); // I start the job in a timer.
private Random rand = new Random();
private List<String> ids = getIds(); // get redis keys.
private ForkJoinPool updateThreadsPool = new ForkJoinPool(32);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
                ForkJoinTask<List<List<Item>>> asyncTask = updateThreadsPool.submit(() -> {
                      return ids.parallelStream().map(id -> getFromRedis(id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                });

                int totalNum = 0;
                List<Item> totalItems = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    totalNum = asyncTask.get().stream().peek(totalItems::addAll)
                         .reduce(0, (num, list) -> num + list.size(), Integer::sum);
                } catch (Exception e) { // do something }
                

                int randIndex = rand.nextInt(totalNum); // this is where it throws exception.
                // says that totalNum is zero. 
                // I'm pretty sure totalItems is not empty, because I print log for that.
                // I tried use int totalNum = totalItems.size(), but I got the same problem.
            }
        }, 1000L, 1000L
);
```

Comment: Shouldn’t `asyncTask.get()` return a `List<Item>`? The horrible code after it, namely `.stream().peek(totalItems::addAll) .reduce(0, (num, list) -> num + list.size(), Integer::sum)` seems to try to aggregate a stream of lists, but unless `Item` is a subtype of `List<Item>`, there is no stream of lists and this code wouldn’t even get through the compiler. Given `ForkJoinTask<List<Item>> asyncTask…` you can simply use `List<Item> totalItems = asyncTask.join(); int totalNum = totalItems.size();` and it should match the size of `ids`.

Comment: @Holger you are right, sorry i used lombok for declaration, and I made a mistake here... It should be List<List<Item>>.

Comment: @Holger and the second: int totalNum = totalItems.size(); I tried this, it will return zero sometimes, like the code above.

Comment: Then, use `List<Item> totalItems = asyncTask.join().stream() .flatMap(List::stream) .collect(Collectors.toList()); int totalNum = totalItems.size();` The key point is, use the API in the intended way and don’t use `catch (Exception e) { }`, as otherwise, `peek` might have caused side effects (like producing a non-empty list) while the failed operation (reducing to a number) produced no result, so you are left with the pre-initialized value, i.e. `int totalNum = 0;` before the `try` block. When you collect a `List`, there is no point in a redundant counting operation, as a `List` has `size()`…